# Add objects to an array

Tags: php

I am trying to make sense of the PHP docs for pushing a value to an existing array.

I want an array of object arrays.  The nested arrays need to be accessed by the array key. I need to add objects one at a time.  So if I go $array[123] I will get back an array of objects.

I have made this code to simulate what I am trying to do:

```
<?php

class Disc {
    public $name;
    public function __construct($name) {
        $this->name = $name;
    }
}

$discs = array();

$discs[123] = array();

$discs[123] = new Disc("blue");
$discs[123] = new Disc("red");

echo var_export($discs);
```

the docs seem to say that if I assign a value to array like this is should be same as array_push() but it doesn't seem to be the case.

What is right way to push objects into the array at the specified key?

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now you're just reassigning `$discs[123]` to red from blue.

To Add to, add a new secondary key

```
$discs[123][0] = new Disc("blue");
$discs[123][1] = new Disc("red");
```

Creating a multidimensional array